# Sort python dictionary by Keys formatted as strings

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary with strings as keys formatted as yyyy-mm-dd and want to sort the dictionary by keys with the earliest dates first:

I am currently using `sorted(datesAndText.keys())` but this isn't reliably working because the month and day fields are not always zero padded.

I have looked at [Sort python dictionary by date keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908686/sort-python-dictionary-by-date-keys) and [How do I sort this list in Python, if my date is in a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589479/how-do-i-sort-this-list-in-python-if-my-date-is-in-a-string) but I can't seem to adopt them to by specific case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure your keys are exactly in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`?  For example:

```
>>> '2010-1-15' < '2010-02-15'
False
```

You may be forced to sort something like this:

```
sorted(d,key=lambda x: [int(y) for y in x.split('-')])
```

Another solution (assuming your years are all 4 digits):

```
sorted(d,key=lambda x: [y.zfill(2) for y in x.split('-')])
```

I'm not sure which would be faster.  I suppose it's a candidate for `timeit`.

Comment: `zfill`: now there's a method we don't see enough of.

Comment: @DanielRoseman -- Yeah.  I actually was thinking it was called `zpad` until I tried it in the interpreter and was reminded that wasn't actually a method name ... It's better than `'0'*(2-len(s))+s` though.

Answer (score 2):

Dates in `yyyy-mm-dd` format sort the same way both alphabetically and chronologically, so you can use standard `sorted`:

```
for k, v in sorted(datesAndText.items()):
    # do something with key and value
```

Comment: this isn't working... I get the following sorted keys: 2012-10-1,
2012-10-3,
2012-8-22

Comment: As @mgilson guessed, `2012-8-22` isn't in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Comment: 2012-10-1, 2012-10-3, 2012-8-22 are not in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. Apply @mgilson's solution.

Comment: Your format is not correct. To do alphabetical sorting you need 2 characters four month and day.

Answer (score 2):

Your format, `yyyy-mm-dd`, allows a lexicographic sort, so your code should work fine unless your values aren't zero padded (ex `2012-10-9` instead of `2012-10-09`).

Fix this problem by relying on a comparison of dates rather than strings:

```
sorted(datesAndText, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

This utilizes the `key` parameter to sorted, which is a function which accepts one argument (an element of the list being compared during sort) and returns a value on which `sorted` can use to sort.

This has the ancillary benefit of allowing you to explicitly [specify the string format](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) of the date, should your data need to change.

Edit:

[mgilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748858/mgilson) brought up an interesting point.  `str.split` is probably more efficient.  Let's see if he's correct:

`strptime` solution:

```
bburns@virgil:~$ python -mtimeit -s"from datetime import datetime;d={'2012-2-12':None, '2012-10-9':None, '1978-1-1':None, '1985-10-9':None}" 'sorted(d, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%d"))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 79.7 usec per loop
```

[mgilson's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748858/mgilson) original `str.split` solution:

```
bburns@virgil:~$ python -mtimeit -s"from datetime import datetime;d={'2012-2-12':None, '2012-10-9':None, '1978-1-1':None, '1985-10-9':None}" 'sorted(d,key=lambda x: [int(y) for y in x.split("-")])'
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.6 usec per loop
```

[mgilson's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748858/mgilson) `zfill` `str.split` solution:

```
bburns@virgil:~$ python -mtimeit -s"from datetime import datetime;d={'2012-2-12':None, '2012-10-9':None, '1978-1-1':None, '1985-10-9':None}" 'sorted(d,key=lambda x: [y.zfill(2) for y in x.split("-")])'
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.4 usec per loop
```

Looks like he's correct!  [mgilson's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748858/mgilson) original answer is 4-5 times faster, and his final answer is 10-11 times faster!  However, as we agreed in the comments, readability matters.  Unless you're presently CPU-bound, I'd still advise going with `datetime.strptime` over `str.split`.

Comment: This would work, but I have a feeling that it would be inefficient -- though I suppose it doesn't hurt to `timeit` and see as well.

Comment: I'd imagine you're correct if compared to your solution based on str.split, however it's a bit more readable, as it conveys the fact that we're sorting dates.

Comment: I love love love performance comparison, though.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889611/one-liner-to-determine-if-dictionary-values-are-all-empty-lists-or-not/5889662#5889662  I suppose I'll just have to add an edit... :-)

Comment: See edits.  `zfill` wins the performance comparison by a full order of magnitude over my solution.  I'm betting however with a larger data set that your original solution and my `strptime` solution are pretty neck-and-neck, since zfill is practically O(1) in this case.  Hooray optimization!

Comment: One minor comment.  In the `strptime` example, you have `sorted(d.keys(),...` whereas the others just have `sorted(d,...`.  It's a minor thing, but that extra function lookup could influence the timings in a small way.

Comment: Actually, I take that back they're all going to perform just as consistently, but the overall time complexity (not just big-O) of `zfill` is much reduced over `strptime` and `int('0000')`...

Comment: Thanks, but I checked the difference between passing `d` and `d`.keys() - the difference is well within the noise on this tiny dataset.  It might come into play on a much larger dict, however.  `d.keys()` does add to the memory complexity unnecessarily, though.  I'll pull it out.

Comment: Could use `d.iterkeys()` instead, but it's really unlikely to make a difference.  You're not creating more *data*, only more *references* which are pretty cheap -- even for reasonably large datasets.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17821/discussion-between-ben-burns-and-mgilson)